# Making a video sharing site, need a videoplayer

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I want a videoplayer like youtube's on my site. What should I look for? I'm making a video sharing site in PHP with MySQL.

Should I look into flash? Maybe you know some good video players that are easy to implement on a site.

Answer (score 3):

uff you have lot of work to do.

[FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/) its an opensource flash based player can you customize and use it in your site

Answer (score 3):

Have you gone through these http://www.vidiscript.com/, http://www.phpmotion.com/ and http://osshare.sourceforge.net/. These are clones of youtube-like video media sharing sites. The source code is freely accessible I guess - you can get some help from it.

Comment: I didn't view the whole vidiscript.com link, but it sure looked like a huge ad to me. The "are you sure you want to leave" pop up on close browser window is a huge turn off. Are they scammers?

Answer (score 1):

[Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) is by far the best I've found. It has a very nice Javascript API that lets you manipulate the video player in every single way you could possibly want.

Comment: jaja, speed matters... I hate that orange bar saying there is new answers :P regards

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be searched for on Google for as either an ["flv player"](http://www.google.com/search?q=flv+player) or a ["flash video player component"](http://www.google.com/search?q=flash+video+player+component). E.G. a [video player skin](http://www.afcomponents.com/components/flv_player_as3/) or [player with media list](http://www.afcomponents.com/components/media_list_as3/).