# Online video streaming

Tags: php, video-streaming

I want to make a video site in which we can upload the video in any format and display it like youtube. How can I do this? My whole site is in PHP I'm a newbie in the video streaming sp plz be descriptive with your answer

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First you need a VideoPlayer written in Flash / Actionscript, there are also a lot of free ones arround in the internet, e.g.: [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/), You also could write you own. You acctually do not net to buy Flash for this. The Flash/Flex compiler `mxmlc` is available for free. You could also write you Flashvideoplayer in [Haxe](http://haxe.org) (also free).

You you do not want the users to switch within the video you could deliver the videos via HTTP, other wise you need an streaming server like: [FlashMediaServer](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) (not free). There are also open source alternatives like [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5) or [haxeVideo](http://haxevideo.org/).

You you do not have the video available in the right format you need to encode them: the best tool for this task could be [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at the [html5 <video> tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/html5_video.asp), this is probably the simplest way. For an example look at the the one from [surfin' safari](http://webkit.org/blog/140/html5-media-support/).

Be aware that some browsers support ogg and others h264, but not both.

Encoding of the video can be made using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) on the server.

Answer (score 0):

One of my websites does this, and it's a MASSIVE pain.
 However, there are websites out there that'll take a video and convert it to an FLV for you (for a price), for example we use a service called Hey!Watch which is reasonably reliable.

If you really want to encode it to flash yourself, you're going to need a full copy of Flash and a LOT of time =]

Comment: "you're going to need a full copy of Flash and a LOT of time (...)" You could just `ffmpeg` or `memcoder` :)

Answer (score 0):

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146468/making-a-video-sharing-site-need-a-videoplayer/1146903#1146903) highly underrated post with 3 great links for open source solutions that are like youtube and fits perfectly your question (and at least [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282683/add-dynamic-video-content-youtube-like-php/2511965#2511965)):

- http://www.vidiscript.co.uk/
- http://www.phpmotion.com/
- http://osshare.sourceforge.net/

I'm posting this here just to point out the links. I think 2 of those 3 questions should be marked as duped anyway.

Comment: I didn't view the whole vidiscript.com link, but it sure looked like a huge ad to me. The "are you sure you want to leave" pop up on close browser window is a huge turn off.  Are they scammers?

Comment: @aaaa that's the scariest broken link indeed! It wasn't like that when I posted. It's fixed now.